# A sequence $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{a_n^2+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> A sequence $\left(a_n\right)$ of real numbers is defined recursively:
>   $$a_1>0, a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{a_n^2+1}$$
>   Prove that there exists an positive integer $n$ for which
>   $$a_n>\frac{7}{10\sqrt n}$$

*I do not know how to begin to solve this problem*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let we set $b_n = \frac{1}{a_n}$. We have:

$$ b_{n+1} = \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{a_n^2+1}{a_n} = b_n+\frac{1}{b_n}\tag{1}$$
hence if we set $c_n=b_n^2$ it follows that:
$$ c_{n+1}=b_{n+1}^2 = c_n+2+\frac{1}{c_n^2}\tag{2} $$
and by induction it follows that $c_n > c_0+2n$, but also that for any $\varepsilon>0$, $c_n\leq (2+\varepsilon)n$ for any $n$ big enough. It should be easy to finish from here: notice that $\left(\frac{10}{7}\right)^2$ is slightly bigger than $2$.

Comment: Why "also that for any $ε>0, c_n≤(2+ε)n$ for any $n$ big enough"?